# javascript click event doesnt respond

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have written a wordpress plugin where I print main stream and when a user click main stream, it toggles the subjects belong to main stream. However, it works for the front end.

I wanted to implemnt this in wordpress backend also.
Every thing works except the toggle function.

I have included jquery in admin-header file in wordpress.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // dynamically handlling main streams and their subjects
        // when a main stream is selected, it is sub categories(subjects) div will
        // be toggle.
         //        alert(subClicked);
        $(".main_stream").click(function() {
            var subClicked = $(this).attr('id');
            // $(".stream").hide();
    //                    alert(subClicked);
                        console.log("value is "+subClicked);
            $("#" + subClicked + "sub").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I try to debug with firbug,though when I click the mainstream, it doesn't go in to `$(".main_stream").click(function()`. Nothing is changed.

Have I missed anything, I am new to wordpress. I am not sure how jquery is handle in wordpress admin panel. Can anybody give me a hint?

part of generated Html

```
<div id="Statisticssub" class="hide" "="" style="padding-left: 20px;">
<input type="checkbox" id="Technology_Solutions" value="" class="main_stream" checked="checked"/>
Technology Solutions
<br/>
<div id="Technology_Solutionssub" class="hide" style="display: block;" "="">
<div style="width: 350px; height: 30px; padding-top: 5px;">
<div style="width: 350px; height: 20px; padding-top: 5px;">
<div style="width: 260px; float: left; padding-top: 5px;">
<input type="checkbox" id="16" name="check_subjects[]"/>
C#
</div>
<div style="width: 75px; height: 10px; float: left; padding-right: 15px;">
</div>
<div style="width: 350px; height: 20px; padding-top: 5px;">
<div style="width: 260px; float: left; padding-top: 5px;">
<div style="width: 75px; height: 10px; float: left; padding-right: 15px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you including two version of `jQuery` .Keep only one of them

Comment: I removed `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: is `.main_stream`  added dynamically ?

Comment: yes, from the back end php code generate .mainstream class for each main stream.

Comment: Can you show your generated html ?

Comment: [**your code works here**](http://jsfiddle.net/JKLY2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I add the javascript to generate fro backend, problem was solved. I am not sure why javascript in header is discarded before.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure but it sounds like the class isn't present when the event handler for the click is registered, even though you've wrapped it within a doc.ready block. You can try changing the handler signature from a `.click` to `.on`, while targeting the input's parent element in the original selector, and the main_stream class in the handler:

```
$("#Statisticssub").on('click', '.main_stream', function() {
            var subClicked = $(this).attr('id');
            // $(".stream").hide();
    //                    alert(subClicked);
                        console.log("value is "+subClicked);
            $("#" + subClicked + "sub").toggle();
        });
```

The `.click` looks for the element you're targeting in the Selector, if it's not there then the handler can't attach. The `.on` call delegates this work, and allows events to fire for things that might be added later.

Read more here: http://api.jquery.com/on/